# Google App Engine authentication failing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, openid

After working on some test code for open ID authentication, I had a break and when I came back, found myself faced with this bizarre warning message from GAE:

```
Error: Unauthorized
Your client does not have permission to the requested URL /.
```

Here is the code I am using for both the .pl code and the .yaml

```
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

builtins:
- remote_api: on

handlers:
- url: /
  script: do_openid_login.py
  login: required
  auth_fail_action: unauthorized

- url: /_ah/login_required
  script: do_openid_login.py
  login: required
  auth_fail_action: unauthorized
```

and

```
class MyLogin(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            greeting = ("Welcome, %s %s %s! (<a href=\"%s\">sign out</a>)" %
                        (user.nickname(), user.email(), user.user_id(), users.create_logout_url("/")))
        else:
            greeting = ("<a href=\"%s\">Sign in or register</a>." %
                        users.create_login_url("/"))

        self.response.out.write("<html><body>%s</body></html>" % greeting)


application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', MyLogin),
], debug=True)


def main():
  run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Is there something that has changed? or have I done something stupid? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `/` to `login: required` which means that you have to be already logged in before accessing it.

Most likely you were testing without having the `login: required` in your `app.yaml` and you were already logged in. You added that line and everything looked fine, but once you logged out or restarted your server you were not logged in anymore, so you got that error.

You should rethink your URL mapping and which URLs should have that parameter and which ones are not, in order not to break the experience. Consider also using redirects if the user is not logged in or showing different responses otherwise.